# sass file not compiled by gulp

Tags: css, node.js, sass, npm, gulp

I want to switch from less to sass so I installed gulp-sass with npm and modified my gulpfile to compile sass instead of less (nothing else changed). Sadly gulp doesn't compile my .scss file to css and after googling and trying all i could think of it still doesn't compile. Here are all the informations I can show you:

**gulpfile.js**

```
// GULP CONFIG

// REQUIRES
    // general
    var gulp = require('gulp');
    // css
    var sass = require('gulp-sass');
    var minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');
    var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
    var rename = require("gulp-rename");
    // watch
    var watch = require('gulp-watch');


// TASKS
    // css 
    gulp.task('css', function() {
            gulp.src('style.css')                                       // get the 'all-import' css-file
            // .pipe(sass({includePaths: ['./styles']}))
            // .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))                 
            .pipe(sass())                                               // sass to css
            .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', { cascade: false }))   // autoprefix
            .pipe(minifycss())                                          // minify
            .pipe(rename('style.min.css'))                              // rename to style.min.css
            .pipe(gulp.dest(''));                                       // output to root
    });

    // watch
    gulp.task('watch', function() {
      gulp.watch('styles/*', ['css']); 
    });


// RUN DEFAULT
gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

**related Folders & Files**

```
├── style.min.css
├── style.css (with @import styles/style.scss)
│    └── styles
│          ├── style.scss
```

**terminal response:**

starting gulp:

```
[10:19:14] Starting 'watch'...
[10:19:14] Finished 'watch' after 11 ms
[10:19:14] Starting 'default'...
[10:19:14] Finished 'default' after 20 μs
```

after saving style.scss

```
[10:19:20] Starting 'css'...
[10:19:20] Finished 'css' after 15 ms
```

**style.scss** (content on purpose of testing obviously)

```
$color: #99cc00;

body {
  background-color: $color;
  .sub {
    color: $color;
  }
}
```

**style.min.css** after running through gulp

```
$color:#9c0;body{background-color:$color;.sub{color:$color}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not telling gulp to watch for sass file. On this line:

```
gulp.src('style.css')
```

You are specifying a css file, not a scss file. Change it to :

```
gulp.src('style.scss') // update, s missing
```

Also, there is no output route specified. This line:

```
.pipe(gulp.dest(''));
```

Should contain your destiny route, and its currently empty.

So, for the root route, something like this should work:

```
.pipe(gulp.dest('./')); // or whatever route you want
```

Anyway, your file structure is a bit weird.

In my opinion, you should create different folders for sass files and compiled ones.

Hope this puts you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
As I mentioned above the style.css does @import the style.scss (because in final use it will include multiple .scss files, this is only for testing so it's only one file).

The destination is empty because it's root/same folder wich works fine. The sass code goes to the style.min.css, the only problem is that it's not compiled.

Comment: You cant do that, you have to use a .scss file that will import all partials and compile them into a css file. Bottom point: you cant compile a css file, its already a css file. You have to compile a scss file, and in there, you can import whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks again for answering, really appreciate it. I did the compiling from the .css file while using less before and it worked fine. Because your comment i tried renaming style.css to style.scss and changing the same in the gulpfile: still doesn't compile. Also if I change the source to  > gulp.src('styles/style.scss') < the result is the same. I think the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: You are getting it wrong. On gulp.src you have to specify a .scss file and on the dest a folder for your css file. Sass is a preprocessor and compiles from sass files to css files. If it finds a css file, it will do nothing, because its already a css file. You just have to change the src to a scss file and the dest to a folder where your files will be compiled. All scss that dont start with underscore, will be compiled as they are. If you need to use partials, you have to name them with an underscore, and those wont be compiled, but it content will be on the files that import it.

Comment: You are absolutely right! I changed style.css to style.scss and gulp.src('styles/style.css') to gulp.src('styles/style.scss') and it works. Strangely it worked like that with .less - i had a style.css dat imported the .less files and got compiled. Thanks a lot for your help, have a great day!

Comment: Sure, no problem, glad to help. Just keep in mind that sass is not less. They are totally different preprocessors. Happy it helps :)